# How to fix no matching unique or primary key for this column-list error in sqlplus?

Tags: sqlplus

I'm trying to write this code.

```
    create table pat_entry (
    pat_no number,
    pat_name varchar2(20),
    pat_sex char(2) CHECK(pat_sex IN ('M', 'm', 'F', 'f') ) NOT NULL,
    pat_age number(3) NOT NULL,
    pat_address varchar2(100) NOT NULL,
    pat_ph_no number(15) NOT NULL,
    pat_entry_date date NOT NULL,
    doc_name varchar(2) NOT NULL,
    diagnosis varchar2(20),
    d_name varchar2(20) NOT NULL,
    constraint pk_patEntry_no primary key(pat_no),
    constraint uk_patEntry_name UNIQUE(pat_name, diagnosis)
    );

    Table created.

    create table pat_chkup (
    pat_no number,
    oc_no varchar2(20) NOT NULL,
    date_of_chkup date NOT NULL,
    diagnosis varchar2(20) NOT NULL,
    treatment varchar2(20) NOT NULL,
    status varchar2(16) CHECK(status IN ('admitted', 'operation', 'regular patient') ) NOT NULL,
    constraint pk_patChkup_no primary key(pat_no),
    constraint uk_patChkup_treatment UNIQUE(treatment),
    foreign key(pat_no, diagnosis) REFERENCES pat_entry(pat_no, diagnosis)
    );
    foreign key(pat_no, diagnosis) REFERENCES pat_entry(pat_no, diagnosis),
                                                        *
```

I did add the pat_no as primary key and diagnosis as a unique key but it shows me that I have this error for creating my foreign key

```
   ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A foreign key must reference some unique key (be it a primary key or not). Here, the unique key in `pat_entry` is `(pat_name, diagnosis)`, but `pat_chkup` references `(pat_no, diagnosis)`.

Just change one to match the other (based on what's correct in your application's logic), and you should be fine.